# Validate input based on radio input

Tags: javascript, input, validation

Is there a way to validate a field text input based on radio button selection? I'm trying to validate a user's input into a Title field, based on the radio selection of whether the identity is male or female.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two radio button with same name attribute. and read value of selected radio button

```
var radio= document.getElementsByName('radioname');
var val;
for(var k =0; k< radio.length; k++){
 if(radio[k].checked){
     val = radio[k].val;
    break;
   }
}
var text = document.getElementById('textfield');
if(val == 'male'){
   validateMale(text);
}
else{
 validateFemale(text);
}
function validateMale(text){
 // validation code
}
function validateFemale(text){
// validation code
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've just revised the question to say that I'm validating a field text input based on the radio selection. I.e, if the selection was "Male", only certain text input values would be allowed: Mr, Master etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="radio" onchange="myFunction()">` and set the function in JS to submit your form like that :

```
var myFunction = function(){
     document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```

There the onchange function in JQuery : http://api.jquery.com/change/